# Android resource linking failed while using braintree library

Tags: android, paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox, braintree-data

I'm currently integrating Braintree in our project. But At the starting point, I'll use Braintree SDK in our project file the show Android resource linking error.
error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

please let me know how to resolve the issue. Don't forget to share your answer

```
    **apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cz.paypal_intergration"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.+'
}
**
```

Comment: Add your app level gradle file.

Comment: You can edit the question and paste it down there!

Comment: @PareshP update the question here please check and share your experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compileSdkVersion 27 to 28 and targetSdkVersion 27 to 28

Answer (score 0):

Update your  compileSdkVersion 27 to 28